# Linux rename single unknown file to new_file.txt

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I have found many examples of batch renaming of multiple files to a new file with the same pattern. However I want to just rename one file to a fixed file name. I am frequently receiving a new file with variable name based partly on the date, but with other random characters in the name. I then want to change the name of the file, so I can do some `sed` operations and then import into a data base. Both files would then be deleted.

| Receive | Want |
| --- | --- |
| `20210809-random-numbers.txt` | `new_file.txt` |

I have tried:

```
mv *.txt new_file.txt
```

Which I didn't think would work as it is multiple option to a single option.

Comment: Please edit your question and include examples of what you've tried and how it didn't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Juts a tiny question about that last sentence in your first paragraph: You say _both_ files should be deleted.  But if you have changed the name of the file to `new_file.txt`, then there is only a single file, right? Or am I misunderstanding what you are wanting to happen?

Comment: I agree with Andy Dalton however I would add that it would be handy to know what your criteria for "new file" is.  You could for example use find to do this but it really depends on the criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to find a file with *today's* date in `YYYYMMDD` format at the start of the filename, and that matches the pattern `YYYYMMDD-*.txt`, and rename that into `new_file.txt`, this `bash` script would do that:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Make non-matching globbing patterns disappear.
shopt -s nullglob

# Get today's date.
printf -v today '%(%Y%m%d)T' -1

# Get names in the current directory matching our pattern.
set -- "$today"-*.txt

# Sanity check.
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        printf 'There are %d names matching "%s-*.txt", expected 1\n' \
                "$#" "$today" >&2
        exit 1
fi

# Inform user of action and proceed.
printf 'Renaming "%s" into "new_file.txt"\n' "$1"
mv -f "$1" new_file.txt
```

This matches names out of the current directory, and if any single file matches our expected format, it is renamed into `new_file.txt`.  If multiple or zero files matches our pattern, then we inform the user of this and terminate.

The matching filenames are kept in the list of positional parameters, i.e. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc., which is set with the `set` built-in command.   The length of this list is maintained by the shell in the special variable `$#`, and we're expecting a single filename to match.

Testing:

```
$ ls
script
$ ./script
There are 0 names matching "20210808-*.txt", expected 1
```

```
$ touch 20210808-blahblah-{1..5}.txt
$ ls
20210808-blahblah-1.txt       20210808-blahblah-4.txt
20210808-blahblah-2.txt       20210808-blahblah-5.txt
20210808-blahblah-3.txt       script
$ ./script
There are 5 names matching "20210808-*.txt", expected 1
```

```
$ rm 20210808-blahblah-[2-5].txt
$ ls
20210808-blahblah-1.txt   script
$ ./script
Renaming "20210808-blahblah-1.txt" into "new_file.txt"
$ ls
new_file.txt script
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date` (`man date`) (the `+format` and the `--date=` options), `find` (`man find`), and some careful shell quoting (`man bash`) and do something like (UNTESTED, but checked with `shellcheck.org`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Yesterday's file
tgt="$(date "+%Y%m%d" --date="yesterday")"
# Today's file
tgt="$(date "+%Y%m%d" )"
# find the file - check to ensure we find only 1 file
file="$(find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${tgt}\*.txt" -print)"
if [[ $(echo "$file" | wc -l) -ne 1 ]] then
    echo "Too many files $file"
     exit 1
fi
echo mv "$file" new_file.txt
# or just process `"$file"` with `sed`.
exit 0
```

Comment: You seem to set `tgt` and then immediately overwrite it with a new value.

Comment: I'm surprised that shellcheck would let through unquoted `$PWD` and the apparently missing `;` or newline before `then`. As well, escaping `*` inside already the quoted string `"${tgt}\*.txt"` will make it literal inside the `find` command. Since you're using bash, you could cleanly use an array `files=( "${tgt}"*.txt )` (with `nullglob` set of course) then test `${#files[@]}` for multiplicity.

Comment: @steeldriver shellcheck didn't allow those. I fat-fingered the final cut-and-paste after shellcheck. My bad.

Comment: @waltinator ahh makes sense thanks for confirming

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
find /your-path-here -name "`date +%Y%m%d`-*.txt" -exec mv {} your-path-here/new_file.txt \;

tested on cygwin: 

pt@ptphoto7 ~
$ ls -l ./test ; find ./test  -name "`date +%Y%m%d`-*.txt" -exec mv {} test/new-file.txt \;
total 3
-rw-r--r--+ 1 pt None 2 Aug 15 13:49 20210810-stuff-and-things.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 pt None 2 Aug 15 13:49 20210812-stuff-and-things.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 pt None 2 Aug 15 13:49 20210815-stuff-and-things.txt

pt@ptphoto7 ~
$ ls -l ./test
total 3
-rw-r--r--+ 1 pt None 2 Aug 15 13:49 20210810-stuff-and-things.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 pt None 2 Aug 15 13:49 20210812-stuff-and-things.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 pt None 2 Aug 15 13:49 new-file.txt

pt@ptphoto7 ~
```

Note: if the new file is embedded several directories deep this won't work well; it's not clear from your question whether or not this is the case.